# Wordpress Integration Issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I have developed a restaurant manager backend application using php. The frontend site is to be started. My client suggests  Wordpress  for the frontend.  So I need to pull data from the database, process and display within Wordpress site. There can be operations in forntend such as selecting restaurants, menu categories, customizing the order with additions, minuses...etc.

I have experience in Wordpress with managing themes and plugins but fairly new to Wordpress development. I think I cannot accomplish this task with existing plugins as this scenario totally depends on my database fields and highly customized. And there will be no problem if frontend is going to develop without Wordpress.

I have studied Wordpress custom page templates and adding raw php code there. But in my case as I think, this might take long time for me and might be difficult to manage lengthy php code with validations and ...etc.
In the meantime, I'm thinking of developing a regular php site and installing Wordpress in a sub directory like /blog. Then I will call Wordpress API and fetch posts, categories using feeds  from my php site.

So, what would be the most viable solution? Can you provide some ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No one apart from you really knows the answer im afraid, but i can say i have installed wp in a subdirectory and used its functions to pull in posts etc, on a few existing custom sites, and its pretty simple. So that would be my choice

Comment: Depending on how complicated the php app is, you could replicate it's functionality with a plugin like Advanced Custom Fields. It's very easy to create/update and assign fields and you can manipulate the values to do what you want.... Another way would be to use ajax to display data from your app to any WP page/post using shortcodes etc...

Comment: Are you saying my approach is ok or...

Comment: @rajitha Ys, im saying installing wp in a subdirectory should be fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress will allow you to do what you're after.  In cases like this (integrating out-of-band components in a Wordpress setting), one of my personal favorite approaches is to utilize the [Shortcode API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API).  Essentially, you wrap your functionality up into a function (which would be where you introduce your custom functionality), and inside any content region embed the shortcode.

This approach has the advantage of allowing you to leave a standard Wordpress installation alone for the most part.  In this scenario, your shortcode would be coded within a custom plugin of your making.  As you're running your code within a Wordpress stack, you'd have full access to WP native functionality, but there's nothing to stop you from running your own PHP code.

If you need a greater degree of control over WP (for instance, you want to emit a custom HTTP header), you'll need to look into the details of the [Plugin API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API) to find the ideal time to run arbitrary code or to change how WP works.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to use wordpress, I'd suggest making a custom plugin for this stuff.

You can create databases through wordpress http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins

You can query any database in wordpress http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

It shouldn't be too hard to move everything over to wordpress, if that's what your client wants.

Comment: wordpress plugin would be fine. But I have never developed plugins and I have little time.

Comment: @rajitha it's not too bad to learn, I was in a similar situation, for me it only took a week to learn the wordpress api's and convert into a wordpress plugin. The wordpress documentation has pretty good coverage.

Comment: @rajitha, `I have little time`, then hire someone.